# Python os calls don't work in crontab

Tags: python, cron

I am currently writing a script to change my desktop background every one minute, however when I pipe the output to a file I get:

```
** (process:22375): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=134db3df26c562acad27e9cf00000009 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
```

The python script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, random

def main():

    files =  os.listdir("/home/benkaiser/scripts/XKCD_IMAGES");
    nameOfImg = random.choice(files)

    os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/benkaiser/scripts/XKCD_IMAGES/" + nameOfImg)

    print "Finished Fine!";

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the crontab command is:
    * * * * * /home/benkaiser/scripts/changeDesktop.py

I have already made sure the file is executable so that is not the problem. It seems to be to do with the os.system call that gives the error

Comment: try using a full path to `gsettings` - `/usr/bin/gsettings`

Comment: Tried that, still no luck, its the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `gsettings` needs to know what screen to run on.  If you run it in a terminal, it will run on the screen the terminal is on, but if you run it in crontab, it doesn't have any screen in its context.

You might be able to do this by adding a switch to the gsettings command, or an environment variable, to specify the display.  It depends on whether gsettings was ever written to work in a situation where the display couldn't be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab usually does not know about the X server.Try,

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /home/benkaiser/scripts/changeDesktop.py
```

I am not sure if it will work though.

Comment: I saw someone use something similar putting export DISPLAY=:0 before the command, but it didn't work, and neither did your solution. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your setup, but adding `DISPLAY=:0.0` worked for me. Ubuntu 12.04, gnome3, dual monitors

have this entry in crontab

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/german/change-bg.py
```

Comment: Do you mean `* * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/german/change-bg.py`

Comment: what does this do?